# Jasmine-node not showing test results

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, specifications, jasmine-node

I'm using jasmine-node to run tests for my node.js application. The problem is that if I run the tests one by one with specifying the spec file (`jasmine-node spec/file.spec.js`) - then everything looks great - I get (as an example) the output such as `Finished in 0.049 seconds 4 tests, 19 assertions, 1 failure, 0 skipped`.

But if I run tests just by typing the command `jasmine-node spec/` - I don't get the result as mentioned above and I can't see which tests failed or succeeded.

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?
(I use node.js version 0.12.7 and jasmine-node 1.14.3)

Answer (score 0):

try using the `--matchall` option.

e.g. `jasmine-node --matchall spec/`

Comment: While this may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [humile](https://github.com/megahertz/humile) which is alternative Jasmine test runner for Node.js. Just run

`$ npx humile`

It founds all your specs which name ends with `.spec.js` by default.